# Identity column pair

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, identity

In SQL Server 2008 R2, is it possible to declare a (grouping, identity) pair where the identity is individually counted for each grouping value?

For example, in a table called `Invoice` I have these columns:

```
(year INT, invoiceNo IDENTITY (group by year) )
```

This way I could enforce a unique constraint on `year/invoiceNo` automatically by accounting year (required by law).

Comment: There are sequences in 2012 but nothing like this exists "out of the box" in 2008r2.

Comment: Don't think you can do this without using a computed column or a trigger in 2008.  Not sure I understand why it can't be an identity field in itself (which would also still be unique).  Usually this is more of a presentation issue.